# Dropdownlist in Update Panel Populated on SelectedIndexChanged of Another does not Populate

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I do not know what happened here as I know for a fact that this code was working.  The only thing I know for sure that changed in the project was an upgrade to jQuery 3.31.  I have 2 dropdownlists in an UpdatePanel in a modal.  The first list populates as expected.  The second dropdown is supposed to populated OnSelectedIndexChanged event of the first.  The event is firing, and there are 5 records returned, but the dropdownlist is blank.

> UPDATE After looking at previous versions in TFS this did occur after upgrading to jQuery 3.31.

Here is the modal code:

```
<div id="modalTicketReportSelect" class="md-modal colored-header custom-width md-effect-9 primary">
    <div class="md-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close md-close"><i class="icon s7-close"></i></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Ticket Type Report</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body form">

            <div class="panel panel-alt3 panel-transparent">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-cg">
                    <button runat="server" id="btnAddToGrid" type="button" class="btn btn-alt3" data-dismiss="modal" onserverclick="btnAddToGrid_ServerClick" ><i class="icon s7-check"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-alt3 md-close"><i class="icon s7-close"></i>&nbsp;Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="text-danger">Ticket Type</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTicketTypes" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTicketTypes_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="text-danger">Ticket Report</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTicketReport" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the event handler:

```
        protected void ddlTicketTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //log postback
        LoggerBA.Log(DB_Context, Path.GetFileName(Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"]), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, UtilityBA.LoggerLevel.Info, "postback");

        ticketProfileId = Guid.Parse(ddlTicketTypes.SelectedValue);
        ticketProfileName = ddlTicketTypes.SelectedItem.Text;

        //PopulateTicketReports(ticketProfileId.ToString());
        Guid TicketProfileId = Guid.Empty;
        if (Guid.TryParse(ticketProfileId.ToString(), out TicketProfileId))
        {
            LookupListItemBO SReportTypeListItem = LookupListBA.LookupListItem_GetByBothDatakeys(DB_Context, "SYS_REPORTTYPE", "REPORTTYPE_SINGLE");
            Guid ReportTypeId = SReportTypeListItem.LookupListItemId;

            List<CG.Reports.Views.ReportView.SavedReportBO> singleticketreports = CG.Reports.BLL.DevExpressBA.SavedReport_GetByModuleReportTypeId_AndTypeIdentifierId(DB_Context, "TICKET", ReportTypeId, TicketProfileId, true);
            ddlTicketReport.DataSource = singleticketreports;
            ddlTicketReport.DataTextField = "ReportName";
            ddlTicketReport.DataValueField = "SavedReportId";
            ddlTicketReport.DataBind();
            ListItem oSelect = new ListItem("[Make Selection]", "");
            ddlTicketReport.Items.Insert(0, oSelect);
            ddlTicketReport.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ddlTicketReport.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Dev tools reveal no errors on page.  I am stumped!  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is type for `ticketProfileId`. Is it a String or Guid type?

Comment: As I see it, `ticketProfileId` should be of String type and there is no need to use Guid.Parse to set `ticketProfileId`. You are anyways converting the selected value to a guid later on in your code.

Comment: Also, I would recommend you to put a break point in the else part to make sure that ddlTickerReport dropdown items are not being cleared. If it is, then that is the problem and you can easily correct it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  "else" is not being hit.